# Parsing "DateTime.Now"?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I need to translate strings like this:

```
"DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)"
```

into their equivalent expressions.

I'm only interested in the DateTime class. Is there anything built into .Net that'll help me do this, or do I just need to write my own little parser?

Comment: Why do you need to parse code? I don't understand the requirement?

Comment: What would "their equivalent expression" be? I don't know what that means.

Comment: You can employ something like [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) to do the expression parsing for you.

Comment: Does flee work with DateTime? News to me.

Comment: From their site: "Variables of any type can be dynamically defined and used in expressions"  -- "DateTime - A valid .NET DateTime pattern surrounded by #'s. Use the ExpressionOptions.DateTimeFormat property to control the format. Example: #08/06/2008#.ToLongDateString()"

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll look at Flee. The requirement is to read in some xml that describe tests - e.g. "get all new members between then and now". The 'then' and 'now' dates are specified in the xml as variations on "DateTime.Now".

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)` is part of an expression so translating it into it's equivalent expression... i'm not understanding.

Comment: Why not simple do something like?
`string hours = "-7";
DateTime.Now.AddDays(int32.Parse(hours));`

Comment: If you need to translate lets say minutes/hours/days/week simply parse everything down to minutes e.g. 7 Hours = 7 * 60 and when you execute DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(7 * 60).

Comment: @KingCronus It should. You can register any types/methods you wish and it will automatically expose them and their members for parsing. I haven't worked specifically with `DateTime` in FLEE, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: No joy with FLEE. It can parse this "#01/02/2013#", but barfs at this "DateTime.Now". Ah well, thanks for the suggestions, back to hand rolling parsers...

Comment: @PaulHennessey See my answer: tested and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) to do the expression parsing for you. The below code is tested and working in Silverlight (I believe in full C#, it may have a slightly different syntax around creating the expression, but it might work exactly like this anyway)

```
ExpressionContext context = new ExpressionContext();

//Tell FLEE to expect a DateTime result; if the expression evaluates otherwise, 
//throws an ExpressionCompileException when compiling the expression
context.Options.ResultType = typeof(DateTime);

//Instruct FLEE to expose the `DateTime` static members and have 
//them accessible via "DateTime".
//This mimics the same exact C# syntax to access `DateTime.Now`
context.Imports.AddType(typeof(DateTime), "DateTime");

//Parse the expression, naturally the string would come from your data source
IDynamicExpression expression = ExpressionFactory.CreateDynamic("DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)", context);

//I believe there's a syntax in full C# that lets you evaluate this 
//with a generic flag, but in this build, I only have it return type 
//`Object` so we cast (it does return a `DateTime` though)
DateTime date = (DateTime)expression.Evaluate();

Console.WriteLine(date); //January 25th (7 days ago for me!)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, looks exactly what I need. What is ExpressionFactory, is that a FLEE type? I can't see it (I have FLEE version 0.9.26.0).

Comment: @PaulHennessey That could be Silverlight-specific; I use a special compatible build. If you look at their [Getting Started](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GettingStarted&referringTitle=Examples) examples, they use a slightly different mechanism (`context.CompileDynamic` or `context.CompileGeneric`)

Comment: That's it! Thanks Chris, it works with the context.CompileGeneric. Brilliant!